# Why is my code not working anymore despite working earlier?

Tags: c, string

My goal is to **print**

```
program starts...
set value of num to 0
set value of res to 0
<type in> Bye!!
Input(msg): Bye!!
```

by implementing the `file`

```
  SNOL
  INTO num IS 0
  INTO res IS 0
  BEG msg
  INTO num IS 5
  INTO res IS MULT num num
```

and this is my **code** for it.
**Question:**
I am wondering how my **code** worked for some time then stopped working when I added some declaration statements.Now I deleted those statements and tried to change it when the **code** actually worked but now it only works until the scanning of input then after that the program stops.

**Additional question:**
When I continued to finish my **code**, I got errors when I tried to evaluate the last statement in the file because I could not figure out how to compare if the number is float or int. After that, the result should be this where `res = num*num`.

> Evaluating MULT: result is 25

```
bool objectFloat(const char* object){
//check if 1st character is a digit, if not then return false, otherwise return true.
if (!isdigit(object[0]))
    return false;

// Check if the 2nd character to the last are digits or periods.
// If not, return false otherwise return true
int periods = 0;  //initialize how many periods in the object to zero
int i;
//if character is a period then increment periods.
for(i = 1; i<strlen(object); i++){
    if(object[i]=='.'){
        periods++;
    }
//return false if character is not a digit
    else if(!isdigit(object[i])){
        return false;
    }
}
// return true if there is only one period.
return periods == 1;
}

    //function to check if character is a keyobject.
 bool isKeyobject(const char* object){
char keyobjects[11][11]= {"SNOL", "LONS", "INTO", "IS", "MULT", "BEG",           
"PRINT", "ADD", "SUB", "DIV", "MOD"};

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<11; i++){
    // Check if object is equal to keyobjects at index i
    // If yes, return true
    if (isLowerCase(object)){

    return false;}
    if(strcmp(object, keyobjects[i]) == 0){
       return true;
    }
    }
    //object is not equal to any of the keyobjects so return false
    return false;
 }

 //Function to check if every character is an integer
 // If not, return false otherwise return true
bool objectInt(const char* object){


int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(object); i++){
    if (!isdigit(object[i])) return false;
    }

   return true;
}

bool objectIsVariable(const char* object){


// Check if alphanumeric character & lower case
// If not, return false
int i;

for (i = 0; i < strlen(object); i++){

    if (!isalnum(object[i])&&!isLowerCase(object)) return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
   int setNum(const char* object){

if(objectInt(object)){
    int number, num;
    number=atoi(object);
    num=number;
    return num;
}
else if(objectFloat(object)){
    float number, num;
    number=atof(object);
    num=number;
    return num;
}


}
int setRes(const char* object){
    if(objectInt(object)){
    int number, res;
    number=atoi(object);
    res=number;
    return res;
}
else if(objectFloat(object)){
    float number, res;
    number=atof(object);
    res=number;
}
}




 int main(){

FILE *s_path  = fopen("test.snol", "r");

char object[100];

char msg;
const char* IsitIS = "IS";
const char* IsitMULT = "MULT";
const char* IsitMOD = "MOD";
const char* IsitSNOL= "SNOL";
const char* IsitLONS= "LONS";
const char* IsitINTO = "INTO";
const char* IsitADD= "ADD";
const char* IsitSUB= "SUB";
const char* IsitDIV = "DIV";
const char* IsitBEG = "BEG";
const char* IsitNum = "num";
const char* IsitRes = "res";
int number;
int flag = 0;
// Get each object from s_path until end-of-file is reached
while(fscanf(s_path, "%s", &object) != -1) {

    //if it doesn't start with SNOL then end
    if (isKeyobject(object)&&strcmp(object, IsitSNOL)==0){
        printf ("Program starts...\n\n");
    }   
    else if (isKeyobject(object)&&strcmp(object, IsitINTO)==0){
    printf ("...Set value of "); 
    }


if(objectInt(object)) {
number = atoi(object);
if (flag == 1)
{
    setNum(object);
    printf("num to %d\n", number);
}
else 
{
     setRes(object);
    printf("res to %d\n", number);
}

}

else if(strcmp(object, IsitNum) == 0) {
flag = 1;
  }
  else if(strcmp(object, IsitRes) == 0) {
   flag = 2;
  }
     else if(isKeyobject(object)&&strcmp(object, IsitBEG)==0){
    printf("input msg\n");
    scanf("%s",msg);
    fscanf(s_path," %s", &object);
    printf ("INPUT(%s): %s\n",object,msg);
   }
  }   
   fclose(s_path);    
   }
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? It looks like there is a typo in the `objectFloat()` function with the comment. `return true.` seems to be on its own line.

Comment: When your program suddenly stops working after a seemingly unrelated change, it's typically because your code *was* broken, and invoking *undefined behavior*.  Pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: Your code is impossible to read; you need to format it properly. Also, you should produce a [mcve].

Comment: `int setNum()` does not always return a value.  (Compiler warnings are so useful)

Comment: `fscanf(s_path, "%s", &object)` lacks a width limit

Comment: "Why is my code not working anymore despite working earlier?"  --> because code is compiled without **all** warnings enabled with a good compiler. About 2 dozen identifiable short-comings exist that a compiler will readily warn about and OP can fix before even running.

Comment: what does setNum return? I simply want to assign the scanned number to num.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++ and I don't see the warnings

Comment: Insure you are compiling in C. Are **all** warnings enabled?

Comment: The calls `setNum(object);... setRes(object);` do not do anything for `main()`.  (Same as if they were eliminated)  Why are they there?  Their return values are not used.

Comment: I just wanted to do num=number and res=result but it gives errors in main

Comment: how do I make the code to return values?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the error
I had to change

```
char msg;
```

to

```
char msg[50];
```

I still need the answer to the additional question though.

Comment: Why 50? `scanf("%s",msg);` is not limited.  A width limit is needed.