# C code. Why does my code not return the proper value in main but prints the right value using function?

Tags: c, string, function

My goal is to print and store the string value of num and res and return them to be used in main using the SetNum and SetRes function AND to use them in arithmetic operations in the succeeding code in the main function. The following code produces

> num to 34
>   res to 4.80873
>   4.00000

where 4.0000 should be the value of res. I wanted to print it to know if SetRes actually returned the right floating point value but it did not. How could I correct this code?

Note: ObjectInt checks if token is integer and ObjectFloat checks if token is Float and object is scanned in a file.

```
int setNum(const char* object)
{
    if (objectInt(object)) {
        int number, num;
        number = atoi(object);
        num = number;
        printf("num to %d\n", num);
    }
    else if (objectFloat(object)) {
        float numberf, numf;
        numberf = atof(object);
        numf = numberf;
        printf("num to %lf\n", numf);
    }
}

int setRes(const char* object)
{
    if (objectInt(object)) {
        int number, res;
        number = atoi(object);
        res = number;
        printf("res to %d\n", res);
    }
    else if (objectFloat(object)) {
        float resf;
        resf = atof(object);
        printf("res to %lf\n", resf);
        return resf;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char object[100];
    int number, result;
    float numf, resf;
    int flag = 0;
    //print number and res  if int
    if (objectInt(object)) {

        if (flag == 1) setNum(object);
        else setRes(object);
    }
    //print number and res  if float
    else if (objectFloat(object)) {

        if (flag == 1) setNum(object);
        else resf = setRes(object);
        printf("%lf", resf);
    }

    else if (strcmp(object, IsitNum) == 0) {
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(object, IsitRes) == 0) {
        flag = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't compile that code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `setRes()` dos not always return a value, even though the return value is used in `resf = setRes(object);`  --> undefined behavior.   Post a [MCVE].  This was pointed out in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53459664/2410359).   I [see many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10414404/robyyyn) about related things without well comprehending the earlier posts.

Comment: Also, `resf` in main may be used uninitialized depending on the value of `flag`.

Comment: This is not the whole code. How is `objectInt` `ObjectFloat`, `IsitNum`, `IsitRes` declared and defined? The `setRes` function returns nothing in case `objectInt` returns true or `objectInt` returns false and `objectFloat` returns false. The `setNum` function has no return statement. Function with return type without return [spawns demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your code will never work as intended. Add `return ..` statements to your functions. The `l` printf modifier has no effect on `%lf` you can just `%f` for floats.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setRes()` function does not return a value if the `if` condition is TRUTHY.

Comment: it returns resf

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: then how will I return?

Comment: @Robyyyn Review code `return resf;` and why it is missing in other  portions of the function.

Comment: I know it does not return at some parts and I left it that way to make sure im returning the appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed resf now by converting object to float by using atof after calling setRes